# How do I use multiple is() selectiors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to write an `if` statement that checks to see a node's parent is one of three selectors via `is()`, however `is()` doesn't support multiple selectors as arguments. How can I accomplish something similar to this?:

```
if ($(this).parent().is('.first','.second','.third')) {
    //do this thing
} else {
    //do this other thing
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.first, .second, .third` is a valid selector:

```
$(this).parent().is('.first, .second, .third')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the example in the [API documentation of `is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

You can specify a comma-separated list:

```
if ($(this).parent().is('.first,.second,.third')) {
    //do this thing
} else {
    //do this other thing
}
```

Comment: While your example is correct, I don't believe it is explicitly explained or exemplified in the API docs.

Comment: @nipponese It is. In the else if-clause `$(this).is(".blue,.red")`